# Is there a way to load in a file on nodejs without packaging it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I wish to have the contents of an entire file evaluated in node - in this case, the angular.js source file.

the code should look something like this:

```
jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;
document = jsdom("<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>");
window = document.parentWindow;
navigator = window.navigator;
(eval-file "angular.js")
angular = window.angular;
```

what would be the best way to write the `eval-file` function so that it blocks until angular.js is loaded and then continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did this:

```
jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;
document = jsdom('<html><head></head><body>hello world</body></html>');        
window = document.parentWindow;
navigator = window.navigator;      
fs = require('fs');
angular_file = fs.readFileSync('angular.js', 'utf-8');
eval(angular_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `require` it -- `require("angular.js");`.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work... it gave the error 'module not found'

Comment: You would need to set up anything else you need (e.g. `window`) before requiring the file.

Comment: Yeah.. I did that... I replaced the last two lines of my answer with require and it did not work